# rebuilding kernel without using apt-get

Tags: debian, kernel, wifi

I am setting up my Macbook Air 6.2 with Debian Jessie.

since I do not have any wireless, I need to set it up manually, but all documentation I find how to do it are using apt-get

```
apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') broadcom-sta-dkms
```

[source](https://wiki.debian.org/wl)

How can I do it without apt-get? I did install the linux-headers and other essential packages manually, but now I am stuck rebuilding my kernel without this short and beautiful command .. -.-'

Comment: It's not clear why you want to avoid using `apt-get`. Is it because you don't have internet on that computer? Try with `--print-uris`

Comment: yes, I only have a wireless connection for which I am trying to install the driver "wl".

Comment: please be specific what to do with --print--uris. noob over here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this could work:

```
apt-get install --print-uris linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') broadcom-sta-dkms
```

That would print the ulr for the `.deb` files you need to download.
You can download them on another computer and copy them through a USB drive.

Later:

```
dpkg -i downloadedfile.deb
```

And so on...